# How do i sum prices through a prediod?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to figure out how to make an operation in my table to get a sum of prices by periods; basically i have 4 tables: 'Rooms','Medias','Details' and 'Prices';
Room is my main table with IDs, and i need to join child tables to get details, media and prices for each unit. That works fine as now:

```
@From as date
@To as date

SELECT  
Unit.Id,
Unit.Description,
Details.Description,
Medias.path,

FROM Unit
LEFT JOIN Details
    ON Unit.Id = Details.UnitId
LEFT JOIN Medias
    ON Unit.Id = Medias.UnitId
```

I now need to add a third join to 'Price' table who has a structure like this:

```
   Id  UnitId      From         To        Price    
  -----------------------------------------------
    1   1855   2022-06-18  2022-07-08  203.8600        
    2   1855   2022-07-09  2022-08-12  128.5700    
    3   1855   2022-08-13  2022-08-19  102.8600  
    4   2600   2022-06-18  2022-07-08  231.8600        
    5   2600   2022-07-09  2022-08-12  322.5700    
    6   2600   2022-08-13  2022-08-19  122.8600
```

What i'm trying to do is to add to my select a sum() of Prices over the period that comes to my stored procedure from the variables @From and @To, to get out a total price for a period passed.

For example passing @From = '2022-07-07' and @To = '2022-07-11' it is supposed to give me:
664.86 (203.8600 + 203.8600 + 128.5700 + 128.5700) for the unit 1855
and
1108.86 (231.8600 + 231.8600 + 322.5700 + 322.5700) for the unit 2600

Hope i made this clear, thank you for helping!

Comment: it is impossible to assist, if we can't see where price is stored and how it connects to a date of whom we don't know also noting about. see [mre] and try to edit your question

Comment: This is exactly the same as your last question. Happy to reopen if you can show why the answer there was not sufficient, I note you haven't used any of the code from it

Comment: Your looking for a day weighted price.   Take a peek at  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=28d815361cf55cb42e56d6ecab255cd0

Comment: @Charlieface I am sorry about that; i just couldn't figure out how to make it work, it probably was just my fault though

Comment: @JohnCappelletti The question is now reopened

Comment: Please clarify exactly how it's different, it does appear you want some weighting but not clear how to calculate that

Comment: In order to make this query work i had two problems:
- sum the price of single days through a period (feb 12 to feb 15 with a price of 100$  was supposed to return 300$ and not just 100$)
- make the query work passing through different prices (and periods), so let's  supposed as in the example i made in my question i have 2 periods with same IDs and the 'From' and 'To' passed as parameters select a period through more than a 'From-To' period, i needed to sum that too. 
The query from the other question didn't work for my problem, but now i will check and try again, i might be the one wrong.

Comment: @RekiosAkios Note in my example, I had to use dateadd(day,-1,@To) to get your desired results.   If you date ranges are INCLUSIVE just remove the dateadd() function

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT  
Unit.Id,
Unit.Description,
Details.Description,
Medias.path,
SUM( Prices.Price ) AS TotalPrice
FROM Unit
LEFT JOIN Details
    ON Unit.Id = Details.UnitId
LEFT JOIN Medias
    ON Unit.Id = Medias.UnitId
-- Can be replaced by a INNER JOIN
LEFT JOIN Prices
    ON Unit.Id = Prices.UnitId
        AND( @From BETWEEN( Prices.From, Prices.To ) OR @To BETWEEN( Prices.From, Prices.To ))
GROUP BY Unit.Id,
Unit.Description,
Details.Description,
Medias.path
```